# Is it possible to swich published target to another target(after upgrade)?

Tags: content-delivery, web8, upgrade

I'm upgrading Tridion 2011 SP1 to SDL Web 8.
It's not only updgrading, but server migration is done at the same time.

Upgrading procedure is following

**CMS:**

1. Import Tridion_cm DB into new DB server (it's Amazon RDS).
2. Upgrade the DB to SDL Web 8
3. Install SDL Web 8 into new CMS server.

**Web site:**

4. Copy all files to new Web server.
5. Import Tridion_Broker DB  into new DB server (it's Amazon RDS).
6. Upgrade the DB to SDL Web 8
7. Install SDL Web 8 microservices and  configure Java Web application.

But there is a problem about publishing.

All items published at Tridon 2011 are marked as published, but they're not actually published to new environment.

So SDL Web 8's user have to publish all items again, even though it's not necessary because all files on Web server have already been copied.
(And after publishing all items, delete publish status to old environment by "Clear-TcmPublicationTarget" command.)

Publishing all items in all publication takes much time (weeks or more than 1 month), and it interrupts daily operation of CMS.

My questions are following.

- Is it possible to switch published target to new one by program(for instance by PowerShell command).
- What is good solution to this issue? I think same issue easily occurs after upgrade.

Regards,

Comment: Take a look here: https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/sdl-web-8-migrating-from-old-to-new-style-publishing-part-1-of-3-the-cmdlet

Comment: It looks exactly I need. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have upgraded your CMS, and also upgraded and moved your website and content delivery services to a new server.

In your CMS, you still see your publication target pointing to the previous content delivery server, and all your pages and components show as published to this 'old' publication target.

If you no longer require to use this old content delivery server, then you can simply change the url of your old publishing target, and point it to the new content delivery server. This way, there is no need to republish everything.

Comment: It's good solution on upgrading from old Tridion, but I use new publishing architecture (Topology Manager and so on),so  it's not available to my case.